# Prolog - How to get the user input of a coordinate?

Tags: prolog

I want to get the user input of a numerical `(X,Y)` coordinate, how should I do that?

For example, I am thinking:

```
read_coordinate(C) :-
      write('type the position of move you want to make as a coordinate:'),
      C is point(X,Y),
      read(C).

%some code for point
point(X,Y):- ...
```

Don't think this works out.

Comment: What does "Don't think this works out" mean? What's the problem with it?

Comment: `is/2` is not a generic substitute for `=/2`. You could try forgetting about `C` (what's it for?) and use `read(point(X,Y))`, but you're going to force the user to enter `point(3,4).` literally at the prompt, which is not super user-friendly. The purpose of your `point/2` predicate later on also is vague; you probably don't need it.